# Instructions for using Rabin Information Dispersal Algorithm (IDA)

Tags: cryptography, crypto++, instructions

I want to work on  Rabin Information Dispersal Algorithm (IDA) using Crypto++ in Linux.

A simple instruction can help me.

Comment: You are being down voted and closed because you effectively asked for a tutorial. You cannot see the close reason ([though you should be able to](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254211/please-allow-new-users-to-view-close-reasons-on-their-questions)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to work on Rabin IDA by using crypto++ in linux, A simple instruction can help me.

At this time, there is no consolidated treatment of the secret sharing schemes.

Your best reference at the moment is in the Crypto++ test program `cryptest.exe`. Take a look at the [`test.cpp`](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/test_8cpp_source.html) and the functions `SecretShareFile`/`SecretRecoverFile` and `InformationDisperseFile`/`InformationRecoverFile`.

The platform - Linux vs Windows vs OS X vs BSD vs .... does not matter. It works the same on all platforms.